# tcolor can not sharp corners

Tags: tcolorbox

```
\documentclass [12pt,a4paper]{jarticle}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[dvipdfmx]{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ascmac}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins} %preamble


% --------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}
    [   colframe    =   blue,
        colback =   white,
        colbacktitle    =   red!40!white,
        coltitle    =   black,  fonttitle   =   \bfseries,
         title      =   My box,
        sharpish corners
        ]
box contents
\end{tcolorbox}




% --------------------
\end{document}
```

log

```
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tcb/sharp corners' and I am
 going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

why？

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please what is documentclass jarticle?

Comment: the `dvipdfmx` was not working for me so I have commented it out in the answer

Comment: I copied your code without changes into a file, ran `platex` and `dvipdfmx` on it, and it compiled without error and showed the correct output. Please check whether you can reproduce the error with the code that you posted. What's strange about the error is that it complains about `sharp corners`, while your example uses `sharpish corners` (but both of them work on my machine).

Comment: @tellme Can you please show your .log file?

Comment: Is there any reason to use `jarticle` (Japanese article) for a document in Italian?

Answer (score 1):

Does this satisfy

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass [12pt,a4paper]{article}% changed from jarticle to article
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ascmac}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins} %preamble


% --------------------
\begin{document}

    \newtcolorbox{twotitle}{%
        colframe=blue,
        colback=white,
        colbacktitle=red!40!white,
        coltitle=black,  
        fonttitle=\bfseries,
        title=My box,
        sharpish corners
    }
        \begin{twotitle}
        box contents
        \end{twotitle}


\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks YES!!  log talian.ldf    See the documentation concerning the babel-italian typesetting 
italian.ldf    on input line 11.

ABD: EveryShipout initializing macros

! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tcb/sharpish corners' and I am
 going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.22         \begin{twotitle}
                             
?

Comment: erros... 
21
Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tcb/sharpish corners' and I am
 going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.

See the pgfkeys package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.21         \begin{twotitle}